kubuntu 24.04 goes to re-login screen after 10 minutes of inactivity, despite disabling 'screen saver' in 'Settings'
and i have to say : it's very annoying.
i have tried turning off the screensaver settings in Settings -> Power Management, but that didn't help.
now one can't even listen to music mixes without constantly babysitting the machine..

Sounds more like it goes to sleep.

nah, i turned that off too..
and if it does go to sleep, it turns off the motherboard, and thus my entire webserver.
